# cant resolve overflow issue for mobile

Tags: css, mobile

Im not sure what to include here, 
I have went through every `width` on the site and cant figure out why Im seeing my site with a margin on the right on mobile devices.

Here is a link 
http://m.mdmobile.hailstorm-technologies.com/
I have tried

`overflow:hidden;` in the `body` and `html` css , and while that resolves the issue on the mobile I cant scroll down on the desktop.

I have tried `overflow-x:hidden` for `body` and `html` and once again, this works for the mobile but adds a second vertical scrollbar onto the shrunk desktop browser.

html {

```
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
width:100%;
overflow-x:hidden;



}

body { 
color: #000000;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
background-image: url('../image/background-pattern.jpg'); 
width:100%;
overflow-x:hidden;  


}
```

Ive also included this...

```
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following line is causing this

```
#header #welcome {
float: left; /* remove this */
z-index: 5;
text-align: left;
color: #006f51;
position: relative;
}
```

EDIT: still some margin there, remove this aswell

```
#header #cart .heading a {
color: #006f51;
text-decoration: none;
float: right;
text-decoration: underline;
margin-right: -10px; /* remove this  */
padding: 6px 10px 6px 30px;
clear: both;
font-size: 17px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much koningdavid  , Id have never have spotted that, I still dont know why that was causing it.

Comment: @Adrian Yeah i dont have a clue either... really weird

Comment: thanks koning, very much appreciated! I still cant figure out the first one, not sure how you saw that, I wouldnt have thought to remove the `float`, but cheers